# AWS SES save email to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I have configured AWS SES for saving emails to AWS S3 bucket. Followed All Steps.
When i try to send verified email at first, it is saved into S3 bucket named as "AMAZON_SES_SETUP_NOTIFICATION".

It does not generate a real email file. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Jacob

Comment: Who downvoted? Do you have solution for it?

Comment: when you receive an email, you should see a new file getting created in your s3 bucket. do you see it happening?

Comment: Well, i have changed the content, i could not be able to see a new generated file. Only "AMAZON_SES_SETUP_NOTIFICATION".

Comment: you must be missing some step. did you configure the MX record?

Comment: I did, and my domain has been verified already.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs

> The bucket may also contain a file named AMAZON_SES_SETUP_NOTIFICATION. You can ignore or delete this file.

This file has nothing to do with the emails you receive, you can delete the file if you want. If you have done all the configurations correctly, whenever you receive an email, you should see a new file getting created in your S3 bucket.

To setup email receiving, you need to publish an MX record as well.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-mx-record.html

Reference:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-getting-started-view.html